# C# regex to extract string between two characters but first character has multiple occurences

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to extract string between two characters. First charachter has multiple occurences and I need the last occurence of first character. I've already checked similar questions but all suggested regexes don't work in case of multiple occurences of first character.

Example:

```
TEST-[1111]-20190603-25_TEST17083
```

My code:

```
string input = "TEST-[1111]-20190603-25_TEST17083";
var matches = Regex.Matches(input,@"(?<=-)(.+?)(?=_)");
var match = matches.OfType<Match>().FirstOrDefault();
var value = match.Groups[0].Value;
```

The current result:

```
[1111]-20190603-25
```

Expected result:

```
25
```

Comment: Please post some code that shows what you're doing.  The problem might not be with the regex but with how you're extracting the result.

Comment: Can you use [`.*` to consume the initial part](https://regex101.com/r/BdZqsk/1)?

Comment: `(?<=-)([0-9]+)(?=_)`? If we can guarantee that exepected result is a number; `(?<=-)([^\-]+?)(?=_)`

Comment: The point is that `.` matches any char. If you know there must be no other `-` in between `-` and `_` use `[^-]` instead of the dot.

Comment: The accepted answer is not accurate considering "*I need the last occurrence*". It will return all occurrences.

Comment: @MohammedNoureldin I've marked both answers as useful. The accepted answer was most helpful for me because it's based on my pattern.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's try a bit different pattern:

```
(?<=-)([^-_]+?)(?=_)
```

we use `[^-_]` instead of `.`:  all characters *except* `-` and `_`

Comment: `-` at the initial position in the character class does not have to be escaped. Actually, you do not need a non-greedy quantifier, use greedy one.

Answer (score 2):

One option to get your result (and there are many options of course) is the following pattern:

```
.*-([0-9]*)_
```

and then get the first matched group (group with Id 1).

So your code will look like this:

```
var input = "[1111]-20190603-25";
var pattern = @".*-([0-9]*)_";

var match = Regex.Match(input, pattern);
var value = match.Groups[1];
```

Comment: Efficient and [takes into account](https://regex101.com/r/0zqxKv/2), that OP wants to match the *last occurence* which eg [this regex doesn't](https://regex101.com/r/0zqxKv/1).